# Scanner.hasNext(Pattern pattern) not working as expected

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

I'm using the Scanner class to parse some text. Maybe my pattern is wrong, but I've tried tweaking it and didn't find a way to make it work, so I'm posting this here:

```
public class StackOverflowExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is a source string example
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("\"field_name\":\"field_value\"");
        // The scanner instance with default values
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
        // Set the scanner delimiter to \b* so it takes blanks as delimiters only if they're there
        scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\b*"));
        // Compile the pattern to match field names
        Pattern field_name_pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\":");
        // Check if scanner finds the first field name
        if (scanner.hasNext(field_name_pattern)) {
            // Field name found, so print it
            System.out.println(scanner.next(field_name_pattern));
        } else {
            // Field name not found, so warn about it
            System.out.println("Oops! It didn't work!");
        }
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is that the scanner matches the first "field_name": substring in the reader and hence return true for the scanner.hasNext(field_name_pattern), but the actual behavior is that it doesn't matches it and so it returns false instead.

Comment: "Not working as expected" is not describing either what you expect or what it is doing instead.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the comments embedded in the code, nonetheless I'm going to edit the question to put it even more clear. (Done!)

Comment: Can you give example inputs and outputs?

Comment: The input is there in the code, in the first line: 

"\"field_name\":\"field_value\""

Comment: The Javadoc of `Scanner.hasNext(Pattern)` says: "Returns true if the next complete token matches the specified pattern.". [If you print the next token](https://ideone.com/WpdQj3), it is the entire string, which doesn't match the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem as pointed out by other users is that the Scanner.hasNext(Pattern pattern) method does NOT work when there's no concrete delimiter. In fact, it needs it to generate the tokens, in its absence the whole string becomes the next token.

The solution is to use Scanner.findInLine(Pattern pattern) method instead as follows:

```
public class StackOverflowExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // This is a source string example
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("\"field_name\":\"field_value\"");
        // The scanner instance with default values
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
        // Compile the pattern to match field names
        Pattern field_name_pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\":");
        // Check if scanner finds the first field name
        String field_name = scanner.findInLine(field_name_pattern);
        if (field_name != null) {
            // Field name found, so print it
            System.out.println(field_name);
        } else {
            // Field name not found, so warn about it
            System.out.println("Oops! It didn't work!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot to those who answered.

Comment: `scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile("\b*"));` serves no purpose since `findInLine` ignores delimiters anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. It's residual code from the previous example. I'm going to remove it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Unless you're using it somewhere else even use of `scanner` is not justified here. You could just use `matcher.find()` to check if a pattern is found in a line.

Comment: You're probably right. I'll weight other options. Or perhaps I could find a way to generalize the delimiter regular expression so it matches other stuff and handle edge cases outside. I'll reflect about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your scanner's delimiter that is failing and returning complete input string as next token to scanner and causing pattern `"\"\\w+\":"` to return `false`.

As per Javadoc of [`public boolean hasNext​(Pattern pattern)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.util.regex.Pattern))

> Returns true if the next **complete token** matches the specified pattern. A complete token is prefixed and postfixed by input that matches the delimiter pattern.

You may want to use colon as delimiter to make it work:

```
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(":"));
```

**Full Code:**

```
// This is a source string example
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("\"field_name\":\"field_value\"");
// The scanner instance with default values
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stringReader);
// Set the scanner delimiter to \b* so it takes blanks as delimiters only if they're there
scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(":"));
// Compile the pattern to match field names
Pattern field_name_pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\w+\"");
// Check if scanner finds the first field name
if (scanner.hasNext(field_name_pattern)) {
    // Field name found, so print it
    System.out.println(scanner.next(field_name_pattern));
} else {
    // Field name not found, so warn about it
    System.out.println("Oops! It didn't work!");
}
scanner.close();
```

**Output:**

```
"field_name"
```

Comment: That makes sense, the problem is that there will be other cases where the colon is not a delimiter. Even you could put a colon inside a string value. I think I'll be better off using findInLine Scanner method. I'll upvote your answer, nonetheless. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `findInLine` is different as that causes `scanner` to advance

Answer (score 1):

`Scanner`s break text into tokens, then provide those tokens or allow you to work with those tokens. The delimiter is what determines how to break the tokens apart. From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)):

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace. The resulting tokens may then be converted into values of different types using the various next methods.

In your case, your delimiter is `"\b*"`. With an optional delimiter like that, I wasn't sure what Scanner would do, but your test suggests that it's breaking the whitespace-free text into a single token which doesn't match the specified pattern.

You'll have to find a pattern that works better with your use case if you want to use `Scanner` for this. You could also potentially just use regular expressions without a scanner if that's a better fit for your use case.